# Send email to Facebook Application Users

Tags: facebook, email, facebook-fql

In my app I have already asked for extended permission to obtain the email address of all my Facebook Application Users. Now... how can I obtain all these emails to advice purpose?
I've tried this but with no success:

```
select email from user WHERE is_app_user=1
```

I obtain the following error:

> Your statement is not indexable. The
>   WHERE clause must contain an indexable
>   column. Such columns are marked with *
>   in the tables linked from
>   http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql

Surfing the web I understood that it's up to you to save the mail addresses in your servers or somewhere. Is it correct? Does exist a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

It means that the attribute `is_app_user` in `WHERE` clause does not have [index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_%28database%29) in the database, hence facebook will not execute the statement. You can only use the attributes marked by `*` on [this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/) page.

Indexed attributes in user table are: uid, name, username, third_party_id

Workaround is to store fb_id of the users using your application as soon as they join. You can also store email address of the user when he/she joins. I will prefer storing the fb_id of the user as it permits the user to revoke email permissions whenever he wishes to do so.